# Rust - does mpsc::Receiver need to be in a Mutex to be used with Arc?

Tags: rust, channel

I am reading https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html and it states the following:

> ...taking a job off the channel queue involves mutating the receiver, so the threads need a safe way to share and modify receiver; otherwise, we might get race conditions...

However when I look at the [Receiver::recv docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv) it shows that the method takes an immutable reference, so why is the book implying that: Receiving from the Receiver mutates it and thus should be Mutex'd?

Would it not work correctly just behind an Arc (no mutex)?

Comment: The problem is that `Receiver` [is not `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#impl-Sync), so even though `recv()` takes `&self`, it's still not allowed to share a receiver between threads.

Comment: And in case you're wondering *how* and *why* `recv()` takes `&self` if it mutates the value... How: through interior mutability. Why (i.e. why not just have `recv()` take `&mut self`): because this way it's much easier for different data structures *inside the same thread* to share a receiver.

Comment: Also note that `recv()` taking `&self` is considered a design mistake.

Comment: This is interesting and revealing, to me, @ChayimFriedman ! :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

We know because in the [Trait Implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#impl-Sync) section of the documentation we see that it implements:

```rust
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T> !Sync for Receiver<T> {}
```

This means it can not be shared safely without some form of synchronization structure such as a mutex.

That being said, you probably wont want to use a mutex. *mpsc* stands for Multiple Producer, Single Consumer. You likely want mpmc (Multiple Producer, Multiple Consumer) channels instead. The [`crossbeam-channel`](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel) provides this type of functionality and is the most popular crate *(that I know of)* for channels. You can create multiple receivers for a single channel by cloning the first receiver.